# Android out of memory error

Tags: java, android, memory

I have an app that needs to synchronize 3 database tables that it holds with the Android contacts list.

I loop through the contacts list and I create a custom object for each row returned and compare that objects properties with what i have stored in my apps table for that contact.

This task is performed in an Async task.

It works fine for me the first time it runs, but if I leave the app and come back more than once it breaks and the following errors are returned. Any ideas?

```
09-03 06:42:19.070: E/IMemory(31018): cannot dup fd=1023, size=2097152, err=0 (Too many open files)

09-03 06:42:19.070: E/IMemory(31018): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x1197738), size=2097152, fd=-1 (Bad file number)

09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)

09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018): java.lang.RuntimeException: No memory in memObj
09-03 
06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):  at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
09-03 
06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):  at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:518)
09-03 
06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):  at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:27)
09-03 
06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):  at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:493)

09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:496)
09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):    at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:103)
09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
09-03 06:42:19.070: E/JavaBinder(31018):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
E/IMemory(31018): cannot dup fd=1023, size=2097152, err=0 (Too many open files)

android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
```

These two lines suggest you are messing up something with Cursors, like not closing etc.,

I would suggest close all cursors properly and observe the behavior of app.